# How to check number of std::hash locally?

Tags: smart-contract, hash

I can not reproduce hash number of these code at local neither at ubuntu or mac environment.

Can anyone tell me how to write a local code that can reproduce the hash result. 
Below is the code

hash value: 4036725243

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/crypto.h>
#include "types.hpp"// #include "eosio.token.hpp"
#include "utils.hpp"
uint8_t compute_random_roll(const std::string& seed1, const std::string& seed2) {
    size_t hash = 0;
    //hash_combine(hash, sha256_to_hex(seed1));
    //hash_combine(hash, sha1_to_hex(seed2));
    hash_combine(hash, seed1);
    hash_combine(hash, seed2);
    return hash % 100 + 1;
}

CONTRACT hello : public eosio::contract {
public:
    using contract::contract;

    ACTION act1() {

        std::string seed1 = "5ccf6c155474c5ddd1ad68b681c4a8713b4e06df11494d0cf2bd5c5e71b4d1e5";
        std::string seed2 = "b72c663881f411e2b669548b9f96dc3705cebf2e";
        std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
        size_t hash = hash_fn(seed1);
        eosio::print("hash  = ", hash);

        eosio::print("bet  = ", compute_random_roll(seed1, seed2));

  }

  ACTION receipt(std::string debug) {
      require_auth(_self);
  }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (act1)(receipt))
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with the help of my amazing teammates, a big thank you to them. 
Apparently, the reason I cannot reproduce the hash is because I used std::hash inside hash_combine function. And in different platform it may result differently. std::hash use MurmurHash2 at 32-bit platform and CityHash at 64-bit platform. And EOS node would use 32-bit one. So now I use MurmurHash2 directly and I am able to reproduce the Hash number.